# How to change color of table row with if else statement in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a simple `ng-repeat` and what I want to do is, if the `p.product_quantity < 10`, the background color will be red. Here is my code:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="p in products" style="background-color: red">
        <td>{{p.product_code}}</td>
        <td>{{p.product_name}}</td>
        <td>{{p.product_quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
```

As you can see with that code, all of the rows will be red. How can I perform an if inside the `<tr>`? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a CSS class and use [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive.

*CSS*

```
.red {background-color: red}
```

*HTML*

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in products"  ng-class="{'red' : p.product_quantity < 10}">
    <td>{{p.product_code}}</td>
    <td>{{p.product_name}}</td>
    <td>{{p.product_quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @FewFlyBy you would have simply got it by searching in Google.

Answer (score 2):

Also there is `ng-style` directive:

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in products"  ng-style="{'background-color': p.product_quantity < 10 ? 'red' : 'white'}">
    <td>{{p.product_code}}</td>
    <td>{{p.product_name}}</td>
    <td>{{p.product_quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class for that.

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in products" ng-class="{'red-bg': p.product_quantity < 10}">
    <td>{{p.product_code}}</td>
    <td>{{p.product_name}}</td>
    <td>{{p.product_quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `ng-class`

> By using ng-class
>   **your template**

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in products" ng-class="bg-read: p.product_quantity < 10">
    <td>{{p.product_code}}</td>
    <td>{{p.product_name}}</td>
    <td>{{p.product_quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```

your css

```
.bg-red {
    background-color: red
}
```

You can find the documentation of ng-class [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and samples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-class.asp)